# Using Perl to expand a string into a list of numbers in Makefile

Tags: perl, makefile

I am trying to expand a variable in the Makefile:

```
 LIST = 1,3-6,9
```

so that "3-6" would expand into a list of numbers between 3 and 6.

I tried the following command in the terminal:

```
echo 1,3-6,9 | perl -pe 's/(\d+)-(\d+)/join(",", $1..$2)/ge'
```

It does produce the exact output. I then tried the following approach in the Makefile:

```
LIST_NEW = $(shell printf $(shell echo ${LIST} | perl -pe 's/(\d+)-(\d+)/join(",", $1..$2)/ge'))
```

which then has the error message as:

```
syntax error at -e line 1, near ", .."
```

How can I solve this issue?

Answer (score 2):

You have to escape any `$` you don't want to be expanded by make, as `$$`.

Also, why are you running `$(shell ...)` twice?

This will work:

```
LIST_NEW = $(shell echo ${LIST} | perl -pe 's/(\d+)-(\d+)/join(",", $$1..$$2)/ge')
```

You might consider using `:=` instead, here, if the value of `LIST` is constant for a given invocation of make.

Comment: Thanks. It does work. I was trying to make it with the two digits form, so it was actually $(shell printf '%02d' ...).

Comment: If you mean you want the output to be `01,03,04,05,06,09` then using `printf` won't work because you're printing a _string_ `1,3,4,5,6,9`, not a number, so printf can't go in and add 0's to all the intermediate values.  You'll have to modify your Perl to print the values with two digits in the first place.

Comment: Yep. That's true. I fixed it. Thank you for your help.